# Grouping by a factor with dodged position in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Let's look at some dummy data. I have various combinations of subjects, treatments and trials. In fact, each subject is only paired with a specific treatment (sounds stupid, but it's just an example).

```
library(ggplot2)
d = read.table(text = '
subject   treatment trial     value
1    1    1    4.5
2    2    1    3.2
3    3    1    1.2
1    1    2    4.8
2    2    2    3.5
3    3    2    1.3
1    1    3    4.2
2    2    3    2.9
3    3    3    1
4    1    1    4.3
5    2    1    3.9
6    3    1    1.1
4    1    2    4.3
5    2    2    3.1
6    3    2    1.8
4    1    3    4
5    2    3    2.6
6    3    3    1.3
', header = TRUE)
d$treatment = as.factor(d$treatment)
d$subject = as.factor(d$subject)
d$trial = as.factor(d$trial)

dodge = position_dodge(.3)
p = ggplot(d, aes(x = treatment, y = value, color = trial, label = subject)) + 
  geom_point(position = dodge) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = pretty_breaks(n = 10)) +
  ylim(1,5) +
  geom_text(hjust = 1.5, position = dodge, size = 3)

print(p)
```

The plot I'm getting is this:

[image]

I would like to add a line between the same subjects, meaning that I would like to combine all the "4"s in the top left corner with a black line.

A simple

```
geom_line(aes(group = subject), position = dodge)
```

doesn't work, though, as it somemhow does not respect the position and just draws a vertical line:

[image]

How else can I achieve that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need to rethink your approach - dodging doesn't work well with lines. Why not use facetting and explicitly display trial on the x axis?

```
ggplot(d, aes(trial, y = value)) + 
  geom_line(aes(group = subject)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = treatment)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = subject), hjust = 1.5, size = 3)  +
  facet_wrap(~ treatment)
```

[image]

.....

Comment: Awesome. I completely forgot about facetting – that makes much more sense for "categorical" x axes anyway.